# How to get the depth of field effect using OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am wondering how to implement the "depth of field/circle of confusion" effect using OpenGL?

Is there any built-in method or library to support it?

Comment: That is [*a lot* of texture lookups](http://www.ati.com/developer/shaderx/ShaderX2_Real-TimeDepthOfFieldSimulation.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

You will not find anything "built in" to OpenGL that will give you what you are looking for. You will have to implement this effect through a shader, which is fairly straightforward.

An article on how to achieve this effect is freely available here:

[Nvidia article on depth of field techniques](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_ch23.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can compute different DOF approximations. For a simple approximation, you could try to render near object into a texture and far object into another texture. In another pass you could blur the texture holding the image of the far objects and then combine both textures to a single texture and wrap it on a screen space rect. This has nothing to do with the actual DOF but in real-time graphics often little tricks are used - but the visual outcome has to be convincing though.